# Dojo file browse control (not upload)

Tags: file, browser, dojo

I need a dojo form control which enables user to browse hard disk and point to file. I dont need to upload that file. JUst a file browser control. I have tried to google it but am unable to find a usable one.

I need a textbox and and a browse button, I want open file dialog to open when I hit browse. User selects the file and full path comes in the text box. I need the the content of textbox as data and not the file itself.

Comment: What exactly you want to do with the file browser.Explain the whole the whole scenario

Comment: I only need the name and full path of the file. I dont want the file to be uploaed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not seen anybody do this before.

You *could* put a plain `<input type="file">` into your HTML, inside a form you never submit, and listen for the `value` of the input element changing.

But I don't think you'll get the full path (at least not in all browsers).

e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/RoystonS/LfMwD/

Comment: It doesnt seems to be possible through javascript. I am now thinking about doing it with Java.

Comment: Well, it's possible in that you can get the basic filename (see the demo I link to above), but browsers do have specific stuff in them to prevent you getting the full path. See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=143220 for instance.